# Error after login : -bash: /bin/bash:: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, authentication, centos

When I login to my centos machine I get the following error:

```
$ sudo su -

date and time here

-bash: /bin/bash:: No such file or directory
```

I would like to know how to fix the bold part when I login.

Comment: check your `.profile` file. It might be calling `/bin/bash`

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.